# sumar valores de dos tablas

Tags: php, sql

hola tengo dos tablas las cuales quiero sumar los valores de ingreso e egreso  de los meses semejantes y tambien sumar ingresos y egresos de meses que no son semejantes.

lo cual yo hice la siguente consulta pero no me suma los valores de los meses que no son semejantes

```
SELECT month(t1.fecha) AS meses,
       SUM(t1.egreso)+SUM(t2.egreso) AS gre,
       SUM(t1.ingreso)+SUM(t2.ingreso)AS ingre 
from deuda t1 
INNER JOIN deuda2 t2 on month(t1.fecha)= month(t2.fecha) 
GROUP BY meses);
```

Comment: podrias agregar cual es el resultado que te lanza?

Comment: mira en ambas tablas tengo ingresos y egresos de meses junio y julio pero solamente tabla 1  tengo ingresos y egresos en noviembre  y en la tabla 2 tengo ingresos y egresos  en agosto. por lo que el resultado que arroja es solamente ingresos y egresos de meses junio y julio

Comment: añade una captura de tu resultado por favor!

Comment: Esta bien tu join? A lo mejor quieres agarrar por ejemplo setiembre 2020 en la tabla 1 y setiembre 2020 en la tabla 2, pero tu join une setiembre 2020, 2019, 2018, etc. Con todos los otros setiembre a que tendría la tabla dos

Comment: Tienes un paréntesis de más en la parte `GROUP BY meses);` de tu consulta.

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar las tablas con algún dato y el resultado que esperas para esa muestra? En SQL, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Primero comprueba la suma para una sola tabla para comprobar que la sintaxis y lógica esta bien, después intenta hacerlo para ambas. aparte el ultimo paréntesis en el group by me parece que esta de sobra

SELECT month(t1.fecha) AS meses,
SUM(t1.egreso) AS gre,
SUM(t1.ingreso) AS ingre
from deuda t1
GROUP BY meses;